# Streaming video from server using VideoView, error (1, -2147483648) with larger files (Sorry, this video cannot be played)

Tags: java, android, streaming, video-streaming, android-videoview

As the title says, I'm trying to stream video to my app using the VideoView. It works completely fine with smaller videos, but for the larger ones, it refuses to play ("Sorry, this video cannot be played" popup, and my server receives a ClientAbortException).

I assume the way it works now is it just downloads the whole file to memory or something and attempts to load it all at once (which is perhaps too much for the device to handle?). I've implemented the chunked streaming functionality on my server (parsing Range headers, etc) but I imagine I need to implement the same functionality client side as well. Can this be done with a VideoView?

Here's my server code (it works fine with the iOS video player, which requests in chunks by default):

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

long begin = 0;
long length, end = file.length();

List<Integer> range = parseRange(request);
if (range.size() > 0) {
    begin = range.get(0);
}           
if (range.size() > 1) {
    end = range.get(1);
}
int dataLength = (int)(end - begin) + 1;

response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
response.setHeader("Content-Range", contentRangeHeaderString(begin, end, length));
response.setContentLength(dataLength);
response.setContentType("video/mp4");

IOUtils.copyLarge(in, out, begin, dataLength);
```

Comment: Did you get the way of handling this in client(android) side? Even i am facing the same problem.I dont know why MediaPlayer of android is not taking care of playing the chunk as soon as it gets.

Comment: @MAHANTESH My workaround was temporarily writing the entire file to disk first, then streaming it off device storage. Not ideal, but the only solution I could come up with.

Comment: It is as good as downloading an video, So why dont you just download it and play it in videoview? send it as attachment the whole video instead of sending it in chunks. Its just my suggestion.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm doing, sorry if my comment wasn't clear. The server side code didn't change, to account for other devices that support range requests. Wouldn't need to anyway, as it supports either request type.